# How to send phone verification code in reactjs with twilio client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, twilio

I'm searching over the internet past 8 hours. I didn't get any tutorial with reactjs. Is their any best tutorial to send sms with twilio in reactjs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

We do not recommend that you make calls to our REST API from the front end of your website as you would expose your account credentials leaving them open to abuse from a malicious attacker.

What you should do is build an action as part of your server that makes the [API requests to send messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages), that you then call from your React app via Ajax.

You tagged the question Node.js so here is a link to a [guide to sending SMS messages in a Node.js application](https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/sms/how-to-send-sms-messages-in-node-js#send-a-message-with-media-mms).

Comment: thanks. I don't have knowledge in nodejs. I know little bit to install modules. Can you please give me the sample code for ajax call? I'm very new to this technologies.

Comment: I have created the ajax request to my code. I'm getting succes response only but not sending sms. @philnash...

Comment: Ok, so what code have you written to perform the message sending? Can you edit your question with what you have so far?

Comment: Thanks @philnash. I have rectified

Comment: Thanks @philnash, you really simplified the process for me. Do you recommend any text messaging provider?

Comment: @Niyongabo I work for Twilio, who provide an API for text messaging, so I very much recommend Twilio! 